# MathJax 3: Is bold \text{} possible?

Tags: mathjax

`\boldsymbol{}` works well for math expressions, but it doesn't work for text:

```
\boldsymbol{A_{\text{Circle}}}
```

[image]

Is there a way to make the `Circle` bold, too?

Comment: Which configuration have in MathJax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\textbf` instead of `\text`:

```
\boldsymbol{A_{\textbf{Circle}}}
```